# Capturing private method arguments with EasyMock and PowerMock

Tags: java, capture, easymock, powermock, private-methods

For public method calls, EasyMock's capture() allows you to intercept & examine arguments passed to the method.  For private method calls, PowerMock's expectPrivate lets you mock private method calls.

Is there a way to somehow combine these and get the arguments passed to a private method call?  Example:

```
public class Program
{
    public FancyReturnType PublicMethod()
    {
        ArbitraryType localInstance = new ArbitraryType();
        localInstance.setFoo(somePrivateHelperMethod());
        localInstance.setBar(increasinglyComplexMagic());

        long aLongValue  = 11235L;
        // more variables, more work

        SomeType worker = privateHelperToIntercept(localInstance, aLongValue, otherVariables);

        if (worker.something)
        {
            return retVal.aFancyReturnType;
        }
        else
        {
            return retVal.anotherFancyReturnType;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, I want to examine the `localInstance` object as it is consumed by the `privateHelperToIntercept()` call.

I've found plenty of examples to mock private method calls; PowerMock's `expectPrivate(partiallyMockedObject, "nameOfPrivateMethod", arg1, arg2)` works great.  I've also found examples to intercept arguments passed to public method calls; `Capture<Type> myTestCapture = new Capture<Type>()` combined with `someMockedObject.PublicMethod(capture(myTestCapture))`.

Unfortunately, I can neither get the two to work together, nor find examples of combining them.  Has anyone seen a way to do this?

FWIW, I suspect Mockito can do this, but it's not included in our source/build/test system.  I'd like to avoid the process of supporting new libraries in our system if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to get a reference to localInstance, then the following code should suffice.

```
@PrepareForTest(Program.class)
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        ArbitraryType passedLocalInstance = new ArbitraryType();
        PowerMock.expectNew(ArbitraryType.class).andReturn(passedLocalInstance );

        //remainder of the test method

        assertEquals(14.2, passedLocalInstance .getValue());
    }
}
```

Since java is pass-by-reference, the passedLocalInstance will be the argument passed into the method call.  Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

`new` of any type is simply a static method. Deal with it in the same way... wrap it in a method, stub out the method. In this case you want to return a mock in your test, and then you can test all the interactions with that object (and remove dependency in your test on the code within the object you are creating which should have it's own tests)

```
public Program {

    // your above code up to object creation
    ArbitraryType localInstance = createArbitraryType();
    // rest of your above code here


  ArbitraryType createArbitraryType() {
    return new ArbitraryType();
  }
}
```

in your test...

```
public class MyTest {
  TestableProgram extends Program {
    @Override 
    ArbitraryType createArbitraryType() {
      return this.arbitraryTypeMock; 
    }
  }

  private ArbitraryType arbitraryTypeMock;
  private TestableMyClass objectToTest = new TestableProgram();

  // rest of your tests...

}
```

Given your constraint's that's how I'd do it.

If could bend your constraints a bit I'd loosen up on the private methods, I've generally done away with private in favor of package default to make testing easier. If the folks IN your package are misbehaving, it's usually your code so private is mostly protecting you from yourself anyway. (but I know that isn't a valid answer your question as posed... ).

Comment: I like the idea, but that unfortunately wasn't an option.  The "Program" class sample was product code and it wasn't a good time to pull out newing ArbitraryTypes through that class.